# Access an app's "private storage" folder (Internal Storage)

Tags: android, internal-storage

MinSDK=24, Target/Compile=27, Java 8

I'm creating a file inside my app's `InternalStorage` folder with this code:

```
File f = new File(context.getFilesDir(),"settings.txt");

if(!f.exists()) {
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

According to `getContext().getFilesDir().getPath();` the folder is `data/user/0/com.xxx.xxx/files` (I'm aware this can change through updates,...) and if I run above code on Android Studio's simulator, the new "settings.txt" file can be accessed through Android Studio's "Device File Explorer".

This doesn't work on an actual phone though (Galaxy S7 with 7.0) because the `user` folder doesn't exist according to the "Device File Explorer".

I know that an app's `InternalStorage` can't be accessed by other apps, so Android's default File Manager probably won't display it but is there a way to access the folder via e.g. Win 10's explorer on an actual Android phone without rooting it? If so, how?

Comment: "This doesn't work on an actual phone though (Galaxy S7 with 7.0) because the user folder doesn't exist according to the "Device File Explorer"." -- the paths as seen from the app and the paths as seen from Device File Explorer will vary. Probably on that S7 you will use `/data/data/com.xxx.xxx/files` in Device File Explorer.

Comment: `/data/data/com.xxx.xxx/` exists but inside there's only a red error message: `run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted` - I already googled it and know that it's a problem with Samsung phones that has to be fixed with a FW update. I also checked in the `sdcard/Android/data` folder (which can also be accessed with Windows Explorer) but there's no app package folder and in `Phone/data/user/0/` (also through Windows Explorer) there are only two "com.samsung.android...." folders.

Comment: Windows Explorer can examine [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html); `getFilesDir()` is [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: I know the difference. ;) I'm re-writing an iOS app for Android and in the iOS version you can access the e.g. settings file through iTunes. I'm looking for a similar way for Android: Something that slightly "inconveniences" the average user and "prevents" them from messing with the files but also giving someone who really has to edit the files the possibility to do so. `InternalStorage` looked promising as it doesn't give other apps access (like `ExternalStorage` would) but if there's absolutely no way to access the files then, I'll have to switch. But before I do so: Question time. ;)

Comment: "Something that slightly "inconveniences" the average user and "prevents" them from messing with the files but also giving someone who really has to edit the files the possibility to do so" -- unless you do that inside of your app, you don't have any options. "if there's absolutely no way to access the files then" -- not without development tools, and my guess is that's too far in the "inconveniences" direction for your use case.

Comment: Something like having to enable the developer settings would be okay but I'm guessing that's not a possibility, is it? What development tools are we talking about? Android Studio? I can't even get its File Explorer to show the files on an actual phone.

Comment: "'m guessing that's not a possibility, is it?" -- correct. "What development tools are we talking about? Android Studio?" -- or command-line stuff, yes. "I can't even get its File Explorer to show the files on an actual phone." -- as you noted, that appears to be a Samsung bug.